# how to trigger time events in php in multiple local timezones

Tags: php, timezone

I have an array that looks like this

```
$alerts = array(
  array('alert' => '04:30:30', 'zone' => 'Europe/Berlin'),
  array('alert' => '04:30:30', 'zone' => 'Asia/Bangkok')
);
```

the challenge is how to trigger this based on local time? 
at times may change plus some continents have summer/winter times others don't ..

Comment: What do you mean with 'trigger' ? are you using PHP as a long running script? Are you writing a cron job?

Comment: Yes its executed every minute by an application.

Comment: I was thinking of a foreach trough the array, using date_defaut_timezone_set and mktime and compare that with +/- 60 sec of the local time, but that seems kind of overdozed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have good timezone identifiers, you should just convert every entry in this array to a `DateTime` object. Then there's no real need to manually calculate when the next occurence is.

After you have your big array of DateTime objects, sort the array so the item that happens first is on top. After that, you calculate how any seconds in the future the trigger should happen and `sleep()` for that long.